# What is the sense of a shared_ptr to a container?

Tags: c++, boost, containers, shared-ptr

What actually is the point of declaring a `boost::shared_ptr` to a container like `std::vector` or `std::list`?

Here is an example utilizing `BOOST_AUTO`.

```
void someFunction()
{
  ...
  BOOST_AUTO(sharedPtrToContainer, boost::make_shared<std::vector<T>>());
  ...
}
```

Is there any sense if you only need the container locally? What is the benefit? What would be the uses of a `shared_ptr` to a container?

Comment: It's the same as declaring a `shared_ptr` to anything else:  you do it because you want the object on the heap but don't want to have to manually `delete` it.  I think your real question is what's the point of allocating the container on the heap if it's only used locally within the function.  Are you sure the function doesn't store the pointer somewhere for use later?

Comment: Will the vector/list have shared ownership?  If so, a shared pointer may make sense.  If not, a shared pointer does not make sense.

Comment: @Wyzard: Thank you for unfolding this!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What actually is the point of declaring a `boost::shared_ptr` to a container like `std::vector` or `std::list`?

Exactly the same point as using a shared pointer to any object type; it allows you to share ownership of the object with other scopes. It doesn't make any difference that the object happens to be a container.

> Is there any sense if you only need the container locally?

No; if you only need it locally, then it should be an ordinary automatic object.

> What is the benefit? What would be the uses of a `shared_ptr` to a container?

If you need to extend its lifetime beyond the current scope, then you'll need to create and destroy it dynamically, and then its lifetime should be managed by smart pointers.

Comment: Four upvotes for explaining basic common sense. Have another!

Answer (score 2):

If you simply declare a container full of pointers to objects allocated on the heap, it's very easy if you're not careful, to allow the container to go out of scope, and at that point, you have a memory leak.  This is because the container only takes ownership of the type that is allocated in the container.  For instance, for a `std::vector<T*>`, the vector will only maintain ownership of allocating memory to contain an series of pointers ... it will not maintain ownership for the objects those pointers are pointing to.  This is simply because it can't ... how would the container know that it was pointing to a heap object and not something else?  And if it were pointing to a heap object, how would it know that it were the only reference to that heap object, and it could delete it when necessary and not create a bunch of dangling pointers?  The reality is because STL containers don't carry that sort of global state information, they can't possibly know the answers to those questions, and therefore the only memory managed by an STL container is the memory it allocates for its own objects that it controls. Thus when a container that is storing pointers goes out of scope, the memory used to allocate the pointers will be properly destroyed, but the container itself will not call `delete` on each pointer to deallocate the object that each pointer was pointing to on the heap.  Using `std::shared_ptr<T>` as the type for an STL container allows the container to pass out-of-scope and remove the memory that was allocated for each `shared_ptr` allocated within the array.  Because of the reference-counting object-state information stored within a `shared_ptr` though, once the last reference to an object has been deleted, it will itself properly destroy the the object on the heap it is managing.  Therefore if you had an STL container that went out-of-scope, any `shared_ptrs` in that container that were the last reference to the object they were pointing to would properly destroy the object on the heap, and you wouldn't end up with a series of memory leaks from pointers being lost to heap objects.

Comment: Thank you for this vast explanation but I was asking about `shared_ptr` to containers not about containers containing `shared_ptr`s.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need it locally, then use an automatic instance:

```
std::vector<T> inst;
```

If you need to return and `T` is heavy (or vector is ridiculously large), then use either the `shared_ptr` or vector of pointers (`T` is heavy and it's small), else return by value, for example `vector<int>`, depending on size, may as well return by value (I guess depends heavily on what the caller is going to do with it)...